# Conditional rowcount

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Emplid        FunctionId          Count 

1-------      2 
1 ------      3   ----------      1 
1 ------      4   ----------      2 
1  ------     4
1 ------      5 ----------        3 
1  ------     6     ----------    4 
1   ------    3      ----------   5 
2    ------   3 
2   ------    3 
2   ------    1      ----------   1 
2    ------   2     ----------    2
```

H&R is looking for a measure to count the flexibility/mobility in the company.

When an Employee is changing from job/function a FunctionID is stored in the DWH empl dim. See the example above how this table looks like (6000 employee records with lots of mutations as well).

So I need a count only when an employee is going to do something else (another function). 
The example above is showing you how the count output should be.

How can do it with T-SqL or in a SSIS package (foreach loop ?)

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: @Arthur, at the very least, you should have a column determining the sort order.

Comment: Does your data have a field you can ORDER BY?  Or some way of knowing which state follows which state?

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer

For given test script, SQL Server honors the order of inserts in the Employee CTE but beware that there is **no** guarantee it would do so every time.

It is imperative that you provide an additional sort order besides EmplId in the `ROW_NUMBER` statement.

#### SQL Statement

```
;WITH EmployeeRank AS (
  SELECT  EmplId
          , FunctionID
          , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmplId)
  FROM    Employee
)
SELECT  er1.EmplID, COUNT(*)
FROM    EmployeeRank er1
        INNER JOIN EmployeeRank er2 
          ON  er2.Emplid = er1.Emplid
              AND er2.rn = er1.rn + 1
              AND er2.FunctionId <> er1.FunctionId
GROUP BY
        er1.EmplID
```

#### Test script

```
;WITH Employee(Emplid, FunctionId) AS (
            SELECT 1, 2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 3 --1        
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 4 --2         
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 4
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 5 --3          
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 6 --4
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 3 --5      
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3 --1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1 --2         
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2 --3         
)
, EmployeeRank AS (
  SELECT  EmplId
          , FunctionID
          , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmplId)
  FROM    Employee
)
SELECT  er1.EmplID, COUNT(*)
FROM    EmployeeRank er1
        INNER JOIN EmployeeRank er2 
          ON  er2.Emplid = er1.Emplid
              AND er2.rn = er1.rn + 1
              AND er2.FunctionId <> er1.FunctionId
GROUP BY
        er1.EmplID
```